# Overriding default Liferay Organization model

Tags: java, liferay

I need to customise Liferay's default behaviour: currently, each organization must hava a unique name -- I need to override this behaviour to allow duplicate names. Also, currently there are lots of entities in current Organization_ table in database.

Is it possible to override default model and remove uniqueness constraint while preserving old entities? If yes, how would I approach this?

Of course, I could just add unique suffixes to new saved entities and remove them on display, but this approach seems wierd.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do this?  I think there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to override default model and remove uniqueness
>   constraint while preserving old entities?

Yes, it surely is, as you can override *everything* in Liferay

> If yes, how would I approach this?

Sarcastic Approach

1. identify *all* the places, where Liferay handles Organizations and might implicitly rely on their uniqueness.
2. hope that I indeed found all the places
3. evaluate if it's feasible to change all those places to not rely on the uniqueness of the name any more
4. *hope* that I found everything, and that my changes make sense
5. set aside a lot of money to pay for future maintenance of my changes, when I need to adopt the changes to future versions of Liferay.
6. to 10. determine that it's not worth it and move on to an alternative solution

Alternative Approach:

1. Determine where this new display is required
2. implement alternative name, e.g. through Expandos (Custom Fields)
3. change display where needed to show the Expando values instead of the organization's name.

Comment: I see. So it is expando then. How would you suggest migrating old names to expando? I am thinking of a simple hook that iterates over existing organizations and copies its current name to corresponding expando value, but I was wondering, if there is a better way?

Comment: "Using the api in any way you're comfortable with" is my recommendation. If that is a hook, the scripting console or a webservice: all work, none is better or worse.